# When a user is deleted are their "accepts" removed?

Tags: support, user-accounts, accepted-answer

When a user is deleted are "accepts" by this user also affected? In other words, will the answer accepted by a deleted user no longer be shown as accepted?

In [one example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725674/how-do-i-change-lubuntus-logout-image) I came across, it appears that at least the "accepted" tick mark remains. But that's just the one example and it's not clear whether the user was removed because of some malfeasance or not.

I'll also point out that when "someone" became user47206, I didn't lose any rep. We shared common interests in LibreOffice, KDE, and LXQt.

Comment: I _think_ so, but I am not sure. But note that we have no reason to suspect malfeasance in this recent deletion either. Which, of course, makes the widespread rep loss caused by the deletion even stranger.

Answer (score 3):

You are **not** going to lose reputation if a user that has accepted your answer is deleted (assuming they have only accepted your answer).

After the user removal, the accept will be owned by the Community user. If you go to the Community's [All actions page](https://askubuntu.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity) and select tab [accepts](https://askubuntu.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=accepts), then you will see that Community has accepted some answers, although it hasn't [any questions](https://askubuntu.com/users/-1/community?tab=questions). How is that possible? It owns the deleted user's accepts of course!

Let's take the first example: [When I turn on my computer, I'm stuck on this: [open for photo]](https://askubuntu.com/q/1135001). The question has an accepted answer, however, since the user is deleted, the accept is owned by Community.

Note that if a user has created a sockpuppet to just create a question and answer it with the main account, then the moderators will simply nuke the account and delete the question, so the reputation will be removed.

[Very related Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738) [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) (although it doesn't mention that it own accepts from deleted users).

Comment: Yeah, I did it and updated some other stuff there.